# iOS Workaround: Smooth scrolling without the CSS property Scroll Behavior: Smooth?

Tags: css, ios, safari, mobile-safari, smooth-scrolling

EDIT: I found a jQuery solution!
https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/dpBMVP
This one indeed works on iOS. I guess jQuery's days of bridging browser support issues aren't quite over yet.

Of course, after searching for many hours and then finally posting to Stack Overflow, I find the solution minutes later. I see a few others made some suggestions in the comments—I'll check those out as well. However this jQuery solution in the Codepen above does the trick and allows for easily customized scroll-speed to boot!

----------------Original Question-----------------------

You may have noticed that neither iOS Safari or iOS Chrome support the CSS property Scroll Behavior: Smooth. My question is: is there another javascript way to animate a scroll to a specific position on the page that does not rely on this CSS property? Perhaps something that scrolls a small amount and then repeats this behavior until the desired target is hit? I tried the following, but I got a "Maximum call size exceeded error":

```
function scrollExperiment() {
    const finalPosition = 500
    let i = 0
    if (i < finalPosition) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        i++
        setTimeout(scrollExperiment(), 10)
    }
} scrollExperiment()
```

Has anyone ever successfully built a workaround like this? I feel like there should be a jQuery solution to this that doesn't rely on the property Scroll Behavior: Smooth, but I haven't found one yet. I tried the following and it still wouldn't scroll smoothly on iOS:

```
$(window).scrollTop($("#anchor").offset().top);
```

Comment: Do you use jQuery in your project? If so you can probably just [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) `scrollTop`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example using jQuery's [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/), as @volt suggested in the comments:

```js
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "500px" });
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>  
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>  
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>    
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>  
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>  
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here text goes here</p>    
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06o8vLuy/)