# JavaScript and css smooth scroll dont work on ios

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I have a problem with javascript. So I have a function that adds scroll to a button and it should be smooth. It works fine on windows and android but doesnt scroll smoothly on ios. Any ideas?

```
const topButton = () => {
    const btn = document.querySelector(".topButton");
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
    }));
}
topButton();
```

Comment: [Safari doesn't support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_scrolltooptions_behavior).

Comment: What shoud i use then instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59814404/ios-workaround-smooth-scrolling-without-the-css-property-scroll-behavior-smoot Check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved the problem